# extracting dataframe with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which consists of more than million values and there is one specific column which consists of some values and some nans. Is there a way I can extract a subset of dataframe which can extract values corresponding the nans?

for example:

I have something in this format

```
+---+----+-----+
| A | B  |  C  |
+---+----+-----+
| 1 | b1 | NaN |
| 2 | b2 | c2  |
| 3 | b3 | NaN |
| 4 | b4 | c4  |
| 5 | b5 | NaN |
+---+----+-----+
```

and I want to extract the data which has a nan in column C:

```
+---+----+-----+
| A | B  |  C  |
+---+----+-----+
| 1 | b1 | NaN |
| 3 | b3 | NaN |
| 5 | b5 | NaN |
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: `df[df['C'].isnull()]` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[np.isnan(df['C'])]
```

This will work if all values are np.number

```
df[df['C'].isnull()]
```

This will work for all datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select those rows by NaN value or use ''.

eg:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
```

try following

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == '']
df.loc[df['column_name'] == NaN]
```

Comment: Nope. `numpy` uses the IEEE 754 standard in which `np.NaN == np.NaN` will return `False`, so you cannot use `==` to find `NaN` values.